# Ordering mixed "section numbers and text" column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a text column with mixed "section numbers" and names, like this:

```
+-----------------+
| Description     |
+-----------------+
|  1.1 First      |
|  1.2 Second     |
|  1.3 Third      |
|  1.10 Tenth     |
|  1.11 Eleventh  |
|  1.20 Twentieth |
|  Unnumbered One |
|  Unnumbered Two |
+-----------------+
```

The number of decimals in the "section number" is not set, so you can have '1' or '1.1' or '1.1.1' or '1.1.1.1' and so on. You can also have just text with no number like the last two lines on the above example.

As it is, if I try to order it by the description it's going to come out like this:

```
select * from myTable order by Description
/*
Output:
  1.1 First
  1.10 Tenth
  1.11 Eleventh
  1.2 Second
  1.20 Twentieth
  1.3 Third  
  Unnumbered One 
  Unnumbered Two
*/
```

The desired output would be something like this:

```
/*
  1.1 First
  1.2 Second
  1.3 Third
  1.10 Tenth
  1.11 Eleventh
  1.20 Twentieth  
  Unnumbered One 
  Unnumbered Two
*/
```

I searched a little on this matter and the usual solution would be the **cast the number as an int**. But since there can be multiple separators in the "section number" and I can't know how many there will be, I've had little success in finding a solution that works both for '1' and '1.1' and '1.1.1' (etc) and orders them in the desired way.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: you can abuse `hierarchyid` to work the same way as numbered headings in literature.

Comment: Usually they do a `padLeft` on string numbers in order to sort them. But this is probably underqualified here

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on Dai's hint.

Just to be clear the Unnumbered One/Two are sorted alphabetically.  We are NOT converting One and Two to 1 and 2

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/h-ulZHk7)**

```
Select *
 From  YourTable
 Order by coalesce(try_convert(hierarchyid,'/'+replace(left([Description],charindex(' ',[Description]+' ')-1 ),'.','/')+'/'),convert(hierarchyid,'/9999999/'))
        , [Description]
```

**Results**

```
Description
1.1 First
1.2 Second
1.3 Third
1.10 Tenth
1.11 Eleventh
1.20 Twentieth
Unnumbered One
Unnumbered Two
```

Comment: Thanks for doing the legwork - I did try to make a quick demo myself but I forgot how to use the `hierarchyid` functions... it's been a while.

Comment: Hmm, methinks this only sorts up to 2 levels deep? I imagine using `STRING_SPLIT` in a TVF would allow for arbitrary-depth sorting.

Comment: @Dai You're 100% correct.   I didn't think it through.   Small tweak required ... Done